# Convert to Correlated Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am asked to find authors who have written more than 1500 pages using a correlated subquery in SSMS. I'm able to easily do this with joins (the below query works), but cannot get this work when I try to convert it to a correlated subquery. Is it even possible? *t.SQLNewbie.*

```
select a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname, sum(t.pages) as tot_pages
from authors a
join title_authors ta
on ta.au_id = a.au_id
join titles t
on t.title_id = ta.title_id
group by a.au_id, a.au_lname, a.au_fname
having sum(t.pages) > 1500
```

Comment: wpuld you please share the tables structure along with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should be in the ballpark:

```
SELECT *
FROM authors a
WHERE EXISTS 
         (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM title_authors ta 
                INNER JOIN titles t ON ta.title_id = t.title_id 
            WHERE ta.author = a.au_id 
            HAVING sum(t.pages) > 1500
         )
```

Comment: @JNevill well you made it clear and simpler corelated subquery :) But Is there any way to remove those joins too and use only corelated subquery as an alternative just like a subquery

Answer (score 0):

Given the nature of the question, I would not use `exists`, but rather a simple comparison:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM authors a
WHERE (SELECT SUM(t.pages)
       FROM title_authors ta JOIN
            titles t
            ON ta.title_id = t.title_id 
       WHERE ta.author = a.au_id 
      ) > 1500;
```

Or even:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM authors a
WHERE (SELECT SUM(t.pages)
       FROM titles t
       WHERE t.title_id IN (SELECT ta.title_id
                            FROM title_authors ta
                            WHERE ta.author = a.au_id 
                           )
      ) > 1500;
```

This manages to get two correlated subqueries into the answer . . . admittedly, at the cost of readability.